# dynamically add event listener for function with variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an option to add additional checkboxes/text fields to my website.  I have a button "+" linked to a function that creates the fields named in numerical order.  I would like to add an event listener to the checkbox that will call a function that requires a unique variable, based on the name of the checkbox that called it.

```html
<div id="container">
    <input name="+" type="button" id="+" onclick="addInput()" value="+" label="+" />
</div>

<p id=demo>eeeeeeee</p>
```

```js
var countBox = 1;

function addInput () {
    var breakNode = document.createElement("br");
    breakNode.className = countBox.toString();

    //create checkbox
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.value = "ProgramSpecificBox" + countBox.toString();
    checkbox.name = "ProgramSpecificBox" + countBox.toString();
    checkbox.id = "ProgramSpecificBox" + countBox.toString();

    //create Amount
    var Amount = document.createElement("input");
    Amount.type = "number";
    Amount.value = countBox.toString();
    Amount.name = "ItemCostVis"+ countBox.toString();
    Amount.id = "ItemCostVis" + countBox.toString();

    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild(breakNode);
    container.appendChild(checkbox);
    container.appendChild(Amount);

    checkbox.addEventListener("click", function () {
        testthis(NEED CODE HERE);
    })

    countBox += 1;
}

function testthis (text) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

What should I put instead of "NEED CODE HERE" to get the same as the id of the checkbox that called the function?

Comment: `this.id` should work. [Test here](http://jsfiddle.net/xmpr6n3e/). However, you might consider a single listener for all checkboxes rather than binding a new listener for each one.

Comment: What does that mean a single listener for all checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
checkbox.addEventListener("click", function()
{testthis(NEED CODE HERE);
})

countBox += 1;
}
```

try:

```
checkbox.addEventListener("click", function(e)
    {testthis(e);
    })

countBox += 1;
}
```

the *e* parameter should be the event object. An event object has a property *currentTarget*, which references the element that initialised the event. Therefore you can call:

```
function testthis(e)
{
    var myvar = e.currentTarget.id;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92v4wL5r/3/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
checkbox.onclick = function(me){window.alert(me.id)};
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  clicking any of the checkboxes gives teh id of the most recent one added.

Comment: @user1930608 or try passing in your count box to your addInput function like `addInput(countBox)` that way each method call has it's own instance variable instead of using the same global variable...in your loop `for(var i = 0; i < ?; i++){addInput(i);}`